# Yahoo manager error using Docker Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://kafka-manager-system/),

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In order to replicate this issue run `docker run zookeeper` then `docker-compose up` on the below `yaml` file.

I am using zookeeper latest image, wurstmeister/kafka:0.9.0.0-1 and [sheepkiller/kafka-manager:latest](https://github.com/sheepkiller/kafka-manager-docker). I ran `docker-compose up` and finallzy got it working but now I get the following error:

[image]

I have searched git and stack over flow with no avail. Everything looks fine until I save a cluster. In the Kafka logs I get:

> [warn] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected
>   error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   kafka-manager_1  | java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   kafka-manager_1  |      at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151] kafka-manager_1  |      at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151] kafka-manager_1  |      at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
>   ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
>   kafka-manager_1  |      at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
>   ~[org.apache.zookeeper.zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]

I also seen this:

```
INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x160fb22e9f50000 type:create cxid:0x2a zxid:0x3e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

This can be replicated by starting zookeeper and taking the below yaml file config and running `docker-compose up`. I have been at this on an off for a week and am not sure why it is not working.

Yaml file:

```
zookeeper:
  image: confluent/zookeeper
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"

kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka:0.9.0.0-1
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"
  links:
    - zookeeper:zk
  environment:
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
    - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
    - KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE=true
    - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_HOURS=1
    - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=10000000
    - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=10000000
    - KAFKA_GROUP_MAX_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS=60000
    - KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS=2
    - KAFKA_DELETE_RETENTION_MS=1000


kafka-manager:
  image: sheepkiller/kafka-manager:latest
  ports:
    - "9000:9000"
  links:
    - zookeeper
    - kafka
  environment:
    ZK_HOSTS: zookeeper:2181
    APPLICATION_SECRET: letmein
    KM_ARGS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Cluster:

[image]

More cluster settings:

[image]
Then I get:

[image]

and then:

[image]

I run docker run -it -d zookeeper, then docker-compose up on that yml file. It starts up but crashes when I create a cluster.

Docker config:

> Containers: 53  Running: 2  Paused: 0  Stopped: 51 Images: 13 Server
>   Version: 17.12.0-ce Storage Driver: overlay2  Backing Filesystem:
>   extfs  Supports d_type: true  Native Overlay Diff: true Logging
>   Driver: json-file Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs Plugins:  Volume: local 
>   Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay  Log: awslogs fluentd
>   gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog Swarm:
>   inactive Runtimes: runc Default Runtime: runc Init Binary: docker-init
>   containerd version: 89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729 runc
>   version: b2567b37d7b75eb4cf325b77297b140ea686ce8f init version:
>   949e6fa Security Options:  seccomp   Profile: default Kernel Version:
>   4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs Operating System: Docker for Windows OSType: linux Architecture: x86_64 CPUs: 2 Total Memory: 1.934GiB Name:
>   linuxkit-00155dc95329 ID:
>   YJE3:ZJKS:BJCF:TY4W:BU2Y:U7ZO:5P4B:PYMQ:SLVH:KTXD:V2OS:XKCD Docker
>   Root Dir: /var/lib/docker Debug Mode (client): false Debug Mode
>   (server): true  File Descriptors: 19  Goroutines: 36  System Time:
>   2018-01-23T09:47:18.7698506Z  EventsListeners: 1 Registry:
>   https://index.docker.io/v1/ Labels: Experimental: true Insecure
>   Registries:
>    127.0.0.0/8 Live Restore Enabled: false

Answer (score 0):

Tune the below mentioned configuration and your timeout error will be fixed.

- kafka-manager.broker-view-thread-pool-size=< 3 * number_of_brokers>
- kafka-manager.broker-view-max-queue-size=< 3 * total # of partitions across all topics>
- kafka-manager.broker-view-update-seconds=< kafka-manager.broker-view-max-queue-size / (10 * number_of_brokers) >
- kafka-manager.offset-cache-thread-pool-size=< default is # of processors>
- kafka-manager.offset-cache-max-queue-size=< default is 1000>
- kafka-manager.kafka-admin-client-thread-pool-size=< default is # of processors>
- kafka-manager.kafka-admin-client-max-queue-size=< default is 1000>

Comment: Please see updated post. I added more of my configuration. It is still not working. I am setting ´Yikes! Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://kafka-manager-system/), Path(/user/kafka-manager/test_cluster/kafka-state)]] after [2000 ms]` now. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I run docker run -it -d zookeeper, then docker-compose up on that yml file. It starts up but crashes when I create a cluster.

Comment: @Drew What is your system configuration ?

Comment: I updated the post. I ran ´docker info` and I am using windows 10